# capture Progress from when

Tags: swift, promisekit

My Promise usage looks like -

```
when(fulfilled: [promise]).then {(response) -> Void in


}.catch { (error) in
    print(error)
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how i can utilize `progress` property from `when.swift` but no luck so far. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

PromiseKit itself has an example:

https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Tests/CorePromise/03_WhenTests.swift#L120-L141

```
func testProgress() {
    let ex = expectation(description: "")

    XCTAssertNil(Progress.current())

    let p1 = after(.milliseconds(10))
    let p2 = after(.milliseconds(20))
    let p3 = after(.milliseconds(30))
    let p4 = after(.milliseconds(40))

    let progress = Progress(totalUnitCount: 1)
    progress.becomeCurrent(withPendingUnitCount: 1)

    when(fulfilled: p1, p2, p3, p4).done { _ in
        XCTAssertEqual(progress.completedUnitCount, 1)
        ex.fulfill()
    }

    progress.resignCurrent()

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 1, handler: nil)
}
```